# PagerSlidingTabStrip shows wrong position of viewPager's item

Tags: android, tabs, android-viewpager, pagerslidingtabstrip

I need to show the 2nd page of viewPager. After

```
viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
```

it really shows the 2nd page. BUT PagerSlidingTabStrip shows the 3rd page... And then if I scroll to any direction - tabs update itself and look/switch correct. And this problem I see only at Nexus-4, but not at the Nexus-5, HTC ONE and other devices...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found the reason, why this is happening. In my code I added a margin to viewPager.

```
   final int pageMargin = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 4, getResources()
            .getDisplayMetrics());
   pager.setPageMargin(pageMargin);
```

And if you remove this margin - you will solve this problem particular. I don't have other ways

Comment: It worked, thanks. I inherited this code so I do not know why someone added the margin in the first place but it looked exactly like yours. Maybe you can explain me what was the thought behind it or if you got it from somewhere?